# gradle PlayRun task: "Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object" when define assetsDirs property

Tags: gradle, playframework

Can you someone help me with definition of this task:

```
task start(type: PlayRun) {
    applicationJar file('dest/build/playBinary/lib/api.jar')
    assetsJar file('dest/build/playBinary/lib/api-assets.jar')
    assetsDirs [file('dest/public')]
}
```

All paths are valid. When I run `gradle start` I always get following error in console:

> Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object

Here is my soft versions:

> Gradle 2.14
>
> Build time:   2016-06-14 07:16:37 UTC Revision:
> cba5fea19f1e0c6a00cc904828a6ec4e11739abc
>
> Groovy:       2.4.4
>
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
>
> JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
>
> OS:           Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 amd64
>
> platform play: '2.4.8', scala: '2.11'

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-playrun-task-cannot-invoke-method-getat-on-null-object-when-define-assetsdirs-property/19028/2?u=sleshjdev) is solution:

> assetDirs [] looks to the Groovy compiler like an array access. If you
>   want to assign a list you need an = sign.